# jquery change textarea to read write based on select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have textareas in a form in which I want to change from readyonly to readwrite based on checkbox.
In the below jquery I want the textarea object otherinjcomment which is set to readonly, set to readwrite when otherinj is checked and set to readonly when otherinj is unchecked.

```
$(function(){
    $("#otherinj").change(function{
        If($(this).is(':checked')){
            $("#otherinjcomment").prop('readonly',False)
        } 
        else{
            $("#otherinjcomment").prop('readonly',True)   
        }
    })
})
```

Here is the html

```
<div id="afterdesciption">
    <label for="otherinj">Other(Specify below)</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="otherinj" name="otherinj" value="1">
</div>

<div>
    <textarea name="otherinjcomment" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: $("#otherinj").change(function{ does have  $("#otherinj").change(function(){.  Just messed up the copy.

Comment: Beware the case: If -> if ...

Comment: Also `False` and `True`

Comment: Made the typo changes to no avail. Still fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your textarea has name "otherinjcomment", not id. 
You need this jquery code:

```js
$("#otherinj").change(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    $("[name=otherinjcomment]").prop('readonly',false)
  } 
  else{
    $("[name=otherinjcomment]").prop('readonly',true)   
  }
});
```

$("#otherinjcomment") to $("[name=otherinjcomment]")

Comment: Good catch.  I put in the id to consistent with other code.

Comment: final script is below. I also empty the field before disabling it

Comment: $("#otherinj").change(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            $("#otherinjcomment").removeAttr('disabled')
        } 
        else{
            $("#otherinjcomment").val('').attr("disabled","disabled")    
        }
    })

Answer (score 2):

To make it read only and then read write you can switch the disabled attribute accordingly here is a working example [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jylzj)  and if you have several text fields, then use a class as the selector rather a ID

```
$("#otherinj").change(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    $("#otherinjcomment").attr("disabled","disabled"); 
  } 
  else{
    $("#otherinjcomment").removeAttr('disabled')
  }
})
```